# Rails - Nginx, Passenger is not responding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

I have a problem to get rails running. I'm using nginx, passenger for first time and cannot get it working.

***This site can’t be reached***

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/aws/nginx/oss/install_language_runtime.html) on phusionpassenger, and checked 3 times. Just instead of pulling theirs demoapp I made a new one.

- Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial)
- node -v = v4.8.0
- ruby -v = ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164)
  [x86_64-linux]
- rails -v = Rails 5.0.2

**Passenger Installation:**

```
sudo /usr/bin/passenger-config validate-install

 * Checking whether this Passenger install is in PATH... ✓
 * Checking whether there are no other Passenger installations... ✓
```

**Memory Stats:**

```
---------- Nginx processes -----------
PID    PPID   VMSize    Private  Name
--------------------------------------
28956  1      174.3 MB  0.5 MB   nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
28961  28956  174.3 MB  0.6 MB   nginx: worker process
### Processes: 2
### Total private dirty RSS: 1.16 MB


----- Passenger processes -----
PID    VMSize    Private  Name
-------------------------------
28936  441.1 MB  1.2 MB   Passenger watchdog
28939  654.1 MB  2.9 MB   Passenger core
28945  449.3 MB  1.3 MB   Passenger ust-router
### Processes: 3
### Total private dirty RSS: 5.43 MB
```

**passenger.conf**

```
passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/wrappers/ruby;
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
```

**added line to nginx.conf**

```
 http {
    ...
    include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;
    ...
 }
```

**nginx app setting: (quant.conf)**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name (AWS PUBLIC IP);
    # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    root /home/ubuntu/quant/public;
    rails_env production;

    # Turn on Passenger
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/wrappers/ruby;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue.